# rabbitmq refusing to start

Tags: rabbitmq

I have installed rabbitmq on `ubuntu` and trying to start it using `rabbitmq-server start`, however, I'm getting this error:

```
Activating RabbitMQ plugins ...

0 plugins activated:

node with name "rabbit" already running on "mybox"

diagnostics:

- nodes and their ports on mybox: [{rabbit,38618},
                                       {rabbitmqprelaunch13346,41776}]
- current node: rabbitmqprelaunch13346@mybox
- current node home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- current node cookie hash: 8QRKGluOJOcZ4AAkEdFwQg==
```

so I try to stop it or restart it using `service rabbitmq-server restart` but I get the following error: `Restarting rabbitmq-server: RabbitMQ is not running`

The server's host name `hostname -s` is mybox.

How do I stop the currently running instance, or at least, how do I manage it? I have no access to it and yet I'm not able to run rabbitmq properly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Rabbitmq is set to start automatically after it's installed.
I don't think it is configured run with the `service` command.

To see the status of rabbitmq

```
sudo rabbitmqctl status
```

To stop the rabbitmq

```
sudo rabbitmqctl stop
```

(Try the status command again to see that it's stopped).
To start it again, the recommended method is

```
sudo invoke-rc.d rabbitmq-server start
```

These all work with the vanilla ubuntu install using apt-get

**Still not working?**

If you've tried unsuccessfully to start or restart rabbitmq, check to see how many processes are running.

```
ps -ef | grep rabbit
```

There should be 5 processes running as the user rabbitmq.
If you have more, particularly if they're running as other users (such as root, or your own user) you should stop these processes.

The cleanest way is probably to reboot your machine.

Comment: thanks for the reply. `rabbitmqctl status` is giving the same not running error quoted in my post.

`rabbitmqctl stop` is throwing an error saying that rabbit is not running!!

`invoke-rc.d rabbitmq-server start` same error saying that rabbit is already running :-\

Comment: if you do `ps -ef | grep rabbit` you should see a number of processes there - do you? are they running as the rabbitmq user?

Comment: Hate to get all microsoft on you, but I suggest you reboot.  I have the same list, except 2 things: 1 I'm using erlang 5.7.4 so probably an older install, 2 (more important) I don't have the three processes initiated as root: 11823 11829 11833  - the others are virtually identical. - ps it does look like it's actually running.

Comment: The restart solved the issue. Please update your post so I could accept your answer.

Comment: +1 for this really good answer @GregHNZ. Killing the running processes worked for me. Many thanks

Answer (score 15):

`rabbitmq-server` refuses to start if the `hostname -s` value has changed.

The solution suggested here is **only for test/development environments**.

I had to delete the database to fix it locally.
i.e empty folder `/var/lib/rabbitmq` (ubuntu) or `/usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/`(mac)

Comment: That's `/usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/` on Mac with homebrew

Comment: Any idea what folder this is in Windows?

Comment: This was the issue causing my problems as well, thanks.

Comment: I changed mine to localhost to get it working: `sudo hostname localhost`

Comment: Worked for me after those files got corrupt due to insufficient disk space.

Comment: Answer of @nezda solve my issue. Is there any issue doing that?

Answer (score 12):

Seems like the Mnesia database was corrupted. Had to delete it to get `sudo service rabbitmq-server start` going again !

> $ **sudo rm -rf /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/**

Also make sure that any stray rabbit processes are killed before clearing out

> $ **ps auxww | grep rabbit | awk '{print $2}' | sudo xargs kill -9**

And then

> $ **sudo service rabbitmq-server start**

Answer (score 10):

I had similar problem but these suggestions didn't work for me(restart too). When I run `rabbitmq-server` command, I get a response like that:

```
$/ rabbitmq-server


BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   {error,{cannot_log_to_file,"/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@haber01.log",
                              {error,eacces}}}
....
```

When I checked permissions of `/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@haber01.log` file, I saw that group has not write permisson for that file. So I gave permission to group with that command:

```
/var/log/rabbigmq/$ chmod g+w *
```

then problem has gone!

Maybe this answer help someone.

Comment: ```chmod 777 /var/log/rabbitmq/``` worked for me.Thanks

Comment: DON'T change directory permissions to 777, it's insecure, you should change the owner of the directory instead (probably to `rabbitmq`)

Answer (score 4):

If you use celery, your queues could reach max size and rabbit won't start because of that. Maybe you wouldn't even able to use `rabbitmqctl`, so if you can afford to clean the queues, just remove

`/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@<host>/queues`

on unix (look for mnesia DB path on your system). 
**Be careful:** this will remove everything you have in rabbit, so this is a last solution ever.

Comment: Your answer was helpful to deal with a downed RabbitMQ because the disk was full. The path has slightly changed in 3.7.4. It is something like `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@<host>/msg_stores/vhosts/<HASH-OF-VHOST>/queues/<HASH-OF-QUEUE-NAME>`

Answer (score 2):

My brew version of rabbitmq refused to start (after working fine for years without modification by me) too.

```
$ cat /usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf
CONFIG_FILE=/usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq
NODE_IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
NODENAME=rabbit@localhost
RABBITMQ_LOG_BASE=/usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq
```

I edited out `rabbit@` on `NODENAME` and `brew services restart rabbitmq` started working again.

Comment: This solved my issue but is there any downside of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look what is in the log of the node that you are trying to start. It will be in /var/log/rabbitmq/
It was selinux in my case, rabbit could not bind to its ports.

Answer (score 0):

If the standard stop and start are not working, list the rabbitmq processes that are running using

```
ps aux | grep rabbitmq
```

Kill the beam.smp process using

```
kill -9 {process id}
```

and start the rabbitmq-server again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's related, but in my case configuring proper node name helped me after upgrading.

My error message was confusing at least:

```
Error trying to stop RabbitMQ: :throw:{:error, {:missing_dependencies, [:eldap], [:rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap]}}
```

In Ubuntu 22.04 configuration file is `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` with default (commented out) value:

```
#NODENAME=rabbit
```

I set to the node name I used before upgrading, that is `s1`:

```
NODENAME=s1
```

After this fix, the server started instantly:)