# How to remove Rabbitmq so I can reinstall

Tags: rabbitmq

I was having trouble, so I went into the registry and removed the service entry for rabbitmq.  Now when I try to reinstall it says it already exists but it doesn't start (since I removed it) and I can do a `sc delete rabbitmq`.  How do I totally remove all traces of it and reinstall from scratch?  I guess it exists somewhere and the registry entry is all that is gone and the install program says it us just updating it when I do the `rabbitmq-service install`.  I tried 
`rabbitmq-service remove` but it says it doesn't exist.

Comment: Your question is on Windows and you have accepted answer for Ubuntu, that's a good change indeed

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I would suggest as follows:

```py
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove rabbitmq-server
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove rabbitmq-server
```

It will uninstall `rabbitmq` and purge all data (users, vhost..)

Comment: Ahhhh, my `pstree` output on Ubuntu 16 looks so much more compact now. Not sure how it got on my machine in the first place.

Comment: @sashaboulouds thanks, Only these two commands are required to uninstall RabbitMQ

Comment: Note: The above command will remove the current user from your OS. I suggest do not run this command.

Answer (score 15):

RabbitMQ writes the service information into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ericsson\Erlang\ErlSrv\1.1\RabbitMQ`

To remove RabbitMQ manually you have to:

- remove the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Ericsson\Erlang\ErlSrv\1.1\RabbitMQ`
- remove the directory `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ`
- remove the installation-folder.

Next time I suggest to use the `rabbitmq-service.bat` command to install and remove the service.

you have to execute it as `administrator`

Comment: The mention of `rabbitmq-service.bat` is very helpful here!! It's not easy to find in the rabbitmq documentation how to "re-install" the windows service, which is required sometimes. ("Restart the server after [configuration] changes. Windows service users will need to re-install the service after adding or removing a configuration file."

Answer (score 3):

### for macOS with homebrew

```
brew services stop rabbitmq
brew uninstall rabbitmq
```

remove the directories associated with RabbitMQ  ( If you have any issues with the current version of rabbitmq they persist if the following directories are not removed )

```
rm -r /opt/homebrew/etc/rabbitmq                
rm -r /opt/homebrew/var/lib/rabbitmq
rm -r /opt/homebrew/var/log/rabbitmq
```

install rabbitmq

> Note: brew update is optional but doing it following the [official rabbitmq docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-homebrew.html#installation)

```
brew update
brew install rabbitmq
brew services start rabbitmq
```

if the last command throws an error try

```
 brew services restart rabbitmq
```

if the above command throws an error simply run

```
rabbitmq-server
```

Once you are able to start rabbitmq the below commands should work fine

```
 brew services stop rabbitmq
 brew services start rabbitmq
```

> PS: I didn't remove Erlang in this process

---

Recommended: [Read here on how I arrived at this solution](https://medium.com/@anjantalatatam/how-to-clean-install-rabbitmq-1ae214436b7d)

Answer (score 0):

You have to uninstall the Erlang and Rabbitmq both. After you are done with the uninstall, then try to install the Rabbitmq and it will ask you to install Erlang again.

Comment: you don't need to remove Erlang

Comment: Yes but, sometimes it's necessary for [compatibility reasons](https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html)