# Windows RabbitMQ wont start

Tags: rabbitmq, windows-server-2012-r2

How can I get RabbitMQ `3.6.6` to start on Windows Server 2012 R2? I am using Erlang OTP 19 (8.3).

When I try to run `rabbitmq-server start`, I get the following error message.

```
ERROR: epmd error for host {machinename}: address (cannot connect to host/port)
```

The error that I see in the logs is

```
Error description:
   {could_not_start,rabbit,
       {error,
           {{shutdown,
                {failed_to_start_child,rabbit_epmd_monitor,
                    {{badmatch,noport},
                     [{rabbit_epmd_monitor,init,1,
                          [{file,"src/rabbit_epmd_monitor.erl"},{line,56}]},
                      {gen_server,init_it,6,
                          [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,328}]},
                      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                          [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}}},
            {child,undefined,rabbit_epmd_monitor_sup,
                {rabbit_restartable_sup,start_link,
                    [rabbit_epmd_monitor_sup,
                     {rabbit_epmd_monitor,start_link,[]},
                     false]},
                transient,infinity,supervisor,
                [rabbit_restartable_sup]}}}}
```

The port for epmd is 4369 and I've added a firewall rule to allow it.

Comment: Sounds like an [erlang cookie issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673172/rabbitmq-erlang-how-to-make-sure-the-erlang-cookies-are-the-same)... can you run some basic troubleshooting and update the question with the results?

Comment: @theMayer I copied the erlang cookie from the other node already in the cluster. Here's [the disccusion on rabbitmq-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!searchin/rabbitmq-users/ryan$20gates%7Csort:date/rabbitmq-users/xQkwueKe4Io/W6646szkDwAJ).

Comment: OK. I could reply there, but I don't want to get in the way. If you are running in a network environment where you don't have the ability to turn off the firewalls, (a) your network administrator is a moron and (b) you have a problem there. I would try setting up a virtual machine that you DO have admin rights to, and see if you can get it to work. Dollars to donuts that is the issue.

Comment: My other guess would be installing a newer version of erlang before backing to the old version messed up some environment variable, and your best bet is a clean install of the OS before continuing.

Comment: And while you're at it, use RHEL or some other Linux flavor, rather than trying to deal with Windows and its infinite instability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue revolved around connectivity to a certain Virtual Machine(VM) Host. VMotion was used to move the VM to a different host. Once that was completed the connectivity issues were resolved. Here is the powershell script that I used to test and found useful.

```
$hostname = "machinename"
$ports = 4369, 5672, 5671, 25672, 15672

Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $hostname

foreach($port in $ports){
    Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $hostname -Port $port
}
```