# Restore user "guest" on RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I deleted user "guest" from RabbitMQ web manager acceidentally without leaving any other admin account left.
Now I cannot login into web manager anymore.
Delete the RabbitMQ installation folder and reinstall does not help.
When I try to add user via command, the error message shown below:

```
C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.8.1\sbin>rabbitmqctl add_user guest guest
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@DESKTOP-1UO5NEP'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbit@DESKTOP-1UO5NEP
 * If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@DESKTOP-1UO5NEP']

rabbit@DESKTOP-1UO5NEP:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on DESKTOP-1UO5NEP
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed

  * Authentication failed (rejected by the remote node), please check the Erlang cookie


Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-17552-rabbit@DESKTOP-1UO5NEP'
 * effective user's home directory: C:\Users\danie
 * Erlang cookie hash: fzyCmMMnKvpDaJ2EJpAtqQ==
```

I already make sure RabbitMQ service is running:
[RabbitMQ Service Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmLDQ.png)

Can you teach me how to add back guest user or have a total reset the RabbitMQ? Thank you so much.

Comment: you have another kind of the problem related to the `.erlang.cookie` read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33303461/1858116 to configure the cookie in the right way, then you can re-add the user

Comment: I've tried it, but didn't solve the issue.